# Save Data to text tile using SaveFileDialog?

Tags: vb.net, file, text, dialog, save

I have already viewed the [MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx) but I am still having problems.

I created a super-simple program to multiply two numbers, and display the output in the textbox. Now I need to be able to read that text box value and put the value in a text file, bringing up the save to file dialog when the "Save To File" button is clicked.

```
Private Sub MutiplyBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MutiplyBtn.Click
    Dim FirstNum As Double = Num1.Text
    Dim SecondNum As Double = Num2.Text
    Dim Answer2 As Double = FirstNum * SecondNum
    Answerbox.Text = Answer2
End Sub

Private Sub SaveResultToFile_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveResultToFile.Click
    Dim myStream As Stream
    Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()

    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
    saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True

    If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()
        If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Answerbox.Text)
            myStream.Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Currently, Visual Studio is giving me an error: `Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'WriteAllText' accepts this number of arguments.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx) static method requires the name of the file where the data should be written to.
You could use directly the name selected in the saveFileDialog1

```
If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(saveFiledialog1.FileName, Answerbox.Text)
End If
```

instead if you really want to use the stream opened by OpenFile() method your code should be

```
   If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim sw As StreamWriter = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.OpenFile())
        If (sw IsNot Nothing) Then 
            sw.WriteLine(Answerbox.Text)
            sw.Close()
        End If 
    End If
```

The code is an example, you need to add a bit of error handling

Comment: Thank you, that appears to have fixed it.

Comment: Steve, that works perfectly, but this always overwrites data. How to append text to end of file?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam [File.AppendAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: or use a different [StreamWriter constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Steve, thank you for so fast response! I can't figure out how to use StreamWriter Constructor with the saveFileDialog: saveFileDialog.OpenFile() returns Stream but SW Constructor takes string as argument! I don't understand how to create constructor for stream. Can you show some example?

Comment: Please @Mikhail_Sam post a question.

Comment: Steve, take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43275797/how-to-append-data-to-file-using-savefiledialog

Answer (score 1):

Hi I tried above method but I succeed in this way....

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "TXT Files (*.txt*)|*.txt"
      If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK _
      Then
         My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText _
         (SaveFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBox1.Text, True)
      End If
End Sub
```