# How to append data to file using SaveFileDialog

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, file-io, streamwriter

I want to write data to file, so I use `SaveFileDialog` object:

```
Public Class Form3
    Inherits Form
    Public callerForm3To1 As Form1

    Dim fileStream As Stream = Nothing
    Dim fileSW As StreamWriter = Nothing

    Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        SaveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
        SaveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True

        FlagWriteToFile = False

        If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Btn_writeData.Enabled = True
        End If

    End Sub

   'some code
End Class
```

And after that I write data to this opened file:

```
Sub WriteDataToText(data As Long(), appendData As Boolean)
    'Dim a As New StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.OpenFile(), FileMode.Append) ' ERROR!
    fileSW = New StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.OpenFile())
    If (fileSW IsNot Nothing) Then

        fileSW.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", data) + Environment.NewLine)
        fileSW.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

What I want: sometimes I need to append data to this file, and sometimes overwrite. I create `appendData` for this: if `1` then append if `0` then overwrite. I know I can create `StreamWriter` for file and use `FileMode` for my purposes. But If I use `SaveFileDialog` it's method `OpenFile` returns `Stream`! And I cannot create StreamWriter Constructor (it takes String not Stream).

How to append data to file using `SaveFileDialog`?

Comment: Convert the stream to a string using StreamReader.ReadToEnd

Comment: @Benno can you show me more detailed example? I tried this one: `Dim sr As New StreamReader(SaveFileDialog1.OpenFile) fileSW = New StreamWriter(sr.ReadToEnd, FileMode.Append)` but got error: Empty Path Name Is Not Legal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use OpenFile to append data to the file selected in the SaveFileDialog.
In the MSDN documentation about [SaveFileDialog.OpenFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.openfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can read

> For security purposes, this method creates a new file with the
>   selected name and opens it with read/write permissions. This can cause
>   unintentional loss of data if you select an existing file to save to.
>   To save data to an existing file while retaining existing data, use
>   the File class to open the file using the file name returned in the
>   FileName property.

So you should write your code using the FileName property with the StreamWriter constructor that accepts a boolean True to append data or false to overwrite the file.

```
Sub WriteDataToText(data As Long(), appendData As Boolean)
    Using fileSW = New StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, appendData)
        fileSW.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", data) + Environment.NewLine)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Remember to always use the Using statement around these disposable object to be sure about correct closing and disposing of the Stream and avoid locking conditions

Instead using the File class you could write

```
 Dim newLine = String.Join(" ", data) + Environment.NewLine)
 If appendData Then
     File.AppendAllText(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, newLine)
 else
     File.WriteAllText(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, newLine)
 End If
```

Comment: As I understand, using File Class (instead of SaveFileDialog) is more safety way?

Comment: SaveFileDialog has a different purpose. The StreamWriter class is used internally by the File.WriteAllText and File.AppendAllText. These two methods are handy shortcuts but nothing related to the safety

Comment: Thank you for help!

Comment: Steve, one more question. If I use `StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, True)` it still append data instead of overwrite. What can be done wrong here?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam please read the documentation about StreamWriter. The last parameter is True to append, False to overwrite

Comment: oooh so stupid question... thank you for the patience!